# how can delete a specific version using cmis and alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

I tried delete a specific document version, but only can delete the version if this is the last. For example if have a document with 6 versions, and want delete the version 2.0, i cant delete it. Necessarily i need delete the last 4 versions to delete the version 2.0

i use the next code:

```
Document document = (Document)session.getObject(id);
document.delete(false);
```

also i used this

```
Document document = (Document)session.getObject(id);
List<Document> versions = document.getAllVersions();
Logger.debug("Numero de versiones:"+versions.size() );
for(int i=0;i<versions.size();i++){
   Document version = versions.get(i);
   if("2.0".equals(version.getVersionLabel())){
     version.delete(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the business logic behind what you're trying to do, as in "why" are you trying to delete a specific version?

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a document in alfresco it wil generate an **ID** like this one : `8f5274fe-f08b-4f58-bc15-5f62de5d209d;1.0` this one mean this is a document with **ID** `8f5274fe-f08b-4f58-bc15-5f62de5d209d` and with version `1.0` you can change the version and get the document with his **ID** and changing version number.

To delete the document with your version, you need to substring the document **ID** (it will get the last version), you can learn here how to substring the **ID** : [How to substring](https://www.javatpoint.com/substring) (the length of the **ID** is static).

Hope that helped you.

Comment: i tried change the version, but not happen anything.

Comment: i used that:
Map<String, Object> newProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
newProperties.put(PropertyIds.VERSION_LABEL,"10.0");
document.updateProperties(newProperties);